# What is the difference between xpath //a and .//a in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

What is the difference between the following Selenium xpath

```
 //a[@id="name"]
```

and

```
.//a[@id="name"]
```

What is the use of adding the .(dot) in front of the second xpath?

Thanks in Advance